# Css li height does not fit outer div

Tags: html, html-lists, css

I am trying to create a menu panel.[here](http://jsfiddle.net/sampathpremarathna/wwtC3/) is my menu.As you can see the height of `li` does not fit to the height of `menu` div.I have set same height for both but it appear having some margin with the bottom.I want to that `li` to fill the menu height.

Thank you for any help

like this  :[image: menu]

here my codes

```css
.menu {
  height: 30px;
  width: 780px;
  background-color: #09F;
}

.menu ul {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 30px;
}

.menu ul li {
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Change Account</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! you mark it as answer if it has solved the problem, this wil lhelp other to solve their issue quickly.

Comment: :) ..it didn't allow me click accept at that time and i had to shutdown for catch the bus...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change your CSS a little

```
.menu ul li {
    margin-left:15px;
    height:30px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display:inline-block; 
    float:left;
}
```

change `display:inline` to `display:inline-block`